How can I get the user ratings for specific hotels on Google?
I want to get periodically Google's user ratings for over 1000 hotels. Is there any API and any other way i can retrieve this data.

I did it with the following code:
$ch = curl_init();

$params = json_encode(["textQuery" => "hotels in Alexandroupolis",]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://places.googleapis.com/v1/places:searchText');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Content-Type: ' . 'application/json',
    'X-Goog-Api-Key: ' . MyGoogleApiKey,
    'X-Goog-FieldMask: ' . 'places.displayName,places.rating',
]);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

The result of code
